# Running Visual Studio 2010 in Linux

Tags: linux, rhel, windows

Is there any possible way to run Visual Studio 2010 in Linux (Red Hat)?

Comment: You could try installing with with wine but what are you really looking for?  VS is tightly bound to windows and would be of little help in a Linux environment.

Comment: Thanks for the Comment.Yes. I understand that. Is their any possible way for programming .net application in linux.

Comment: [This question about editors may help you](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/352392/what-is-a-decent-mono-editor) since what you want is a IDE running on Linux to code .Net applications.

Comment: Why are you looking to run VS2010 in Linux in the first place? Maybe we can help point you in a different direction that might help you more in the long run?

Answer (score 5):

VirtualBox running Windows 7 x86 in Seamless mode works wonderfully for VS2010 dev. You can even save the state of the machine and reclaim the resources, starting it back up in an identical state, leaving you on the same line you were editing last time.

You haven't mentioned which Window manager you're using - when using Gnome 2, I got best results keeping my Gnome 2 bar to the top of the screen allowing the Windows taskbar to take the bottom.

As an aside, you haven't mentioned in your question whether you're developing Windows software, or whether the target environment will be Mono under Linux. If it's the latter, you might find MonoDevelop less resource intensive.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the performance of VS2010 in VirtualBox is great, provided your CPU supports VT, enable 2D acceleration and enough memory for debugging.

Answer (score -1):

You will never be able to do it 100% perfect.. i think an hackintosh would be reception here.

Have you thought about VM'ing windows 7 and running it seamlessly? Looks good and will consume  less for the job

Comment: Thanks. 
What about the resources. Will this consume more resources of the system?

Comment: I think doing it that way will consume more resources, but may be your only option, unless you are willing to try a different version of Linux. I will try this MS Linux, but not sure.